# Using FCM Data package to refresh a Flutter screen

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to push Notifications to my flutter app. Now i want to refresh a Screen if a data package arrived. But i only want to do this, if the user is currently watching a specific screen. Is there a chance to get the current Screen?

Comment: Instead of watching current screen, you can use `StreamBuilder` within the specific stream that you want to update, and relay messages from FCM msg handler to that stream builder.